# Ciclo de vida Angular

Tags: angular, async

Estou com algumas dúvidas quanto ao ciclo de vida no Angular 7, ao fazer uma requisição de determinada API preciso antes ter pego seu token que também vem através da API, em outro get.

A dúvida está na sequencia das coisas, venho da programação para sistemas SCADA, onde tudo é meio que arcaico e preciso desenvolver uma pesquisa a toque de caixa em angular, por isso a falta de prática.

Estou chamando o token (que retorna) após o ngOnInit, mas como faço a requisição da API que usa o código logo em seguida, ela retorna como inválida por falta do token, então acredito que estou perdido no ciclo de vida do angular.

### Solicitando o token (um service.ts)

```
         getToken(): Observable<TokenHistorian[]> {
        return this.http.get<TokenHistorian[]>(ApiToken)
          .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('getToken', []))
          );
      }
```

### O model

```
    export class TokenHistorian{
    access_token: string;
}
```

### O component.ts

```
    export class PesquisahistorianComponent implements OnInit {


  

    valorToken: TokenHistorian[];
      tokenFinal: string;
    
    
      constructor(private _api: ApiService) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
       
        this.geraToken();
        console.log('http://localhost/api_cco/ifix/volume_res.php?token='+this.tokenFinal);
     
      }
    
        public geraToken = async () => {
        await this._api.getToken()
        .subscribe(returntoken => {
         this.valorToken = returntoken;
         this.tokenFinal = this.valorToken['0'].access_token;
         console.log(this.tokenFinal);
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
    
    }
```

O console.log abaixo do geraToken() retorna como undefined.

**Questão resolvida!**

Depois de algum descanso sempre pensamos melhor...

Pesquisei um pouco e agora consigo esperar o retorno do httpclient antes de prosseguir com o restante do código (falta implementar um loading)

```
async ngOnInit() {
   await this.geraToken();
   console.log('http://localhost/api_cco/ifix/volume_res.php?token='+this.tokenFinal);}
```

E a função passa a ser assíncrona (não sei se efetivamente).

```
public geraToken = async () => {
await this._api.getToken().then(data =>{
  this.teste =data;
  
  this.tokenFinal = data['0'].access_token;
  console.log(this.tokenFinal);
});}
```

A chamada da API

```
 async getToken(): Promise<TokenHistorian[]> {
return await this.http.get<TokenHistorian[]>(ApiToken).toPromise().then();  }
```

Comment: Olá André. Veja se funciona colocando o console dentro de um ```then()``` na chamada do ```geraToken()```. Como é um função assíncrona, o Angular pode está executando o console antes da requisição de Token finalizar. ficaria algo do tipo ```this.geraToken().Then(() => console.log(url + this.tokenFinal));```

Comment: Consegui usando async Lucas, obrigado pelas dicas.